# Add some listener when i close the window in specific component

Tags: reactjs, components, local-storage

im having trouble with this piece of code :

i want to add a listener that pop item from localStorage when user close the window . but i want it to heappen when user close the window in final component but anywhere i close the window the localStorage pop last item . how to fix that ?

```
/ // When Close Window / When refreshing the window
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
  //     event.preventDefault();
  //     getReservedTable.getReservedTable.pop();
  //     window.localStorage.setItem(
  //       "tablesList",
  //       JSON.stringify(getReservedTable.getReservedTable)
  //     );
  //   };

  //   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

  //   return () => {
  //     window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
  //   };
  // }, []);
```

Comment: Listening to the window close is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Prompt, use Prompt to replace.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt